# Using recursion but encounter "Source not found" and Stackoverflow

Tags: java

I wrote a function to recursively add and print 0~n.
i thought BigInteger can store and manipulate large number.
But I encountered some bug.
I tried to use sysout and set upBoundStr to 10000.
The bug is still there.
Could someone tell me what happened?

---

### My code

```
package playground;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class play1 
{
    String initStr = "0";
    String dStr = "1";
    String upBoundStr = "1000000";
    private BigInteger i = new BigInteger(initStr);
    private BigInteger diff = new BigInteger(dStr); 
    private BigInteger upBound = new BigInteger(upBoundStr); 

    public void countBigInteger()
    {
        i = i.add(diff);
        System.out.printf("%s",i);
        //System.out.println(i);
        if(i.compareTo(upBound)==-1)
        {
            countBigInteger();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        play1 p1 = new play1();
        p1.countBigInteger();       
    }
}
```

---

### Logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF5KB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE1uw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call stack has a limited size. I tried your code and got `StackOverflowError` after printing 6600 numbers. This means that the call stack had enough space for 6600 method calls before it ran out of space. That's the risk of running such a deep recursion.

This has nothing to do with `BigInteger`, since this code fails before you even get near the max value of `int` (or even `short`).

If the goal of this code is to test recursion, you found out that deep recursion has limits. If that code serves some other purpose, you can easily re-write it without using any recursion at all.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much. I just wanted to test recursion . Since i haven't use it for a long time.